# Login form with LDAP authentication first and then query user agains MySQL

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, ldap

I'm creating a login form for a local app, this login form will authenticate first against a LDAP server (username and pwd) and then to a local mySQL DB to check if the user (username provided) is registered on DB and has access to this local app).

I already figure it out the code for the LDAP and also the php query to check if user exist on DB, the problem is that I don't figure it out how to properly write on the php file the cases to manage them:

1. User pass LDAP and exist on DB ->  Send user to main site of app.
2. User pass LDAP but don't exist on DB -> Send message that user don't have access to app.
3. Credentials don't work on LDAP side.

frontend HTML site "index.html"

```
<form action="query.php" method="post">

  <div>
    <label for="username"><b>Username</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username" required>
    <label for="password"><b>Password</b></label>  
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" required>
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

php file  to manage LDAP and then mySQL query  "query.php"

```
<?php
$servername = "app.server.com";
$username = "root";
$password = "something";
$dbname = "app_calendar";
$error = false;

// check LDAP for username and pwd provided
$ldap = ldap_connect("ldap.server.com");
if (@$bind = ldap_bind($ldap, "ls\\".$_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) 
{

  //SQL part to check if user is on app DB
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) 
    {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    $sql = "SELECT name, mail FROM ms_resources.users WHERE laptop = '".$_POST['username']."' LIMIT 1";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
    {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $result2='<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade in">
            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a><strong>User logged in!</strong> Welcome '. $row["name"]. '</div>';
            $error = true;
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        $result2='<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a><strong>Error!</strong> No access granted for user: '.$_POST['username'].'</div>';
    }
    $conn->close();

} 
else 
{

   $result2='<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in">
   <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a><strong>Error! </strong>Invalid credentials!</div>';

}



<div class="container">
        <div>
            <?php echo $result2; ?>    
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I use this last part:

```
<div class="container">
        <div>
            <?php echo $result2; ?>    
        </div>
    </div>
```

To send a bootstrap error but after that don't know how to redirect to proper cases, I will appreciate any advise

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's